# Uncaught exception of an async method in Visual Studio 2013 in an iOS project - how to get proper stack trace?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await, visual-studio-2013

When debugging an iOS application in Visual Studio, I often end up with something like this:

[image: Break in Main]

An uncaught exception occurred. The Call Stack window does not show anything interesting.
If I go to the Immediate Window and type

```
$exception
```

I can see the correct stack trace. Usually it's coming from some async method, like in the case below. Why doesn't VS display me that information in the Call Stack window and let me directly step to the root issue?

```
$exception
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at TestClient_Core.Services.Implementations.DefaultDatabaseService+<GetUserSettingAsync>d__37.MoveNext () [0x0003e] in c:\Users\rene\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test  Development\Test.Clients.Mobile\TestClient_Core\Services\Implementations\DefaultDatabaseService.cs:260 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TestClient_Core.Entities.UserSettingEntity].GetResult () [0x00033] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter_T.cs:59 
  at TestClient_Core.LocalDataAccess+<GetUserSettingAsync>d__19.MoveNext () [0x0001e] in c:\Users\rene\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test  Development\Test.Clients.Mobile\TestClient_Core\LocalDataAccess.cs:213 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.String].GetResult () [0x00033] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter_T.cs:59 
  at TestClient_Core.ViewModels.InitializeAppViewModel+<Initialize>d__4.MoveNext () [0x000bc] in c:\Users\rene\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test  Development\Test.Clients.Mobile\TestClient_Core\ViewModels\InitializeAppViewModel.cs:123 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00033] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:60 
  at TestClient_iOS.Controllers.InitializeAppController+<ViewDidAppear>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00030] in c:\Users\rene\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test  Development\Test.Clients.Mobile\TestClient_iOS\Controllers\InitializeAppController.cs:66 }
    base: {System.SystemException}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by the "stack trace window"? Do you mean the "Call Stack" view? If so, bear in mind that this is a *logical* stack trace - it's not like any single thread has that stack at any point in time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated my question. I was referring to the "Call Stack" window/tab. What do you mean by "logical"? When will I see the stack in that window and when not?

Comment: Well normally for synchronous calls, you'll see the actual stack of a thread - method A calls method B calls method C etc. With async methods that gets a lot more complicated, as method A *started* method B which *started* method C, but then later in the execution of method C there may not be that stack any more (e.g. it's a continuation directly in the thread pool). Do you see the same behaviour in non-Xamarin projects? Can you reproduce it in a short but complete program?

Comment: I do not have a non-Xamarin test case, sorry. I'll have an eye on it and report if I have news.